# Show that the sum of a non-negative series is the supremum of its finite partial sums

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sup \{\sum_{n\in F} a_n:F\subseteq \mathbb{N}  \text{ is finite}\}$.

I don't know where to begin, anything will help.

Comment: Hint: First, prove that for all finite sets, the sum over that set is less than the infinite sum.  Second, prove that if the sum converges, then there are finite sums which are closer to the limit than any tolerance $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Suppose first that the sum is convergent. You have to do two things:

1. Show that for each $F \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{n \in F} a_n \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$. This holds because the $a_i$ are non-negative.
2. Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $F \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n \in F} a_n \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n - \epsilon$. Here my hint is to use the definition of convergence of an infinite series, which allows you to find such an $F$ given an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.

If the sum is divergent, we have to modify the second step: you need to show that for every $L > 0$ there exists $F \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n \in F} > L$. Here my hint is to use the definition of divergence of an infinite series.

Note that since $a_i \geq 0$, the sum either converges or diverges to infinity.

Comment: The OP doesn't state that the sum converges, but it looks like you're assuming that it converges.

Comment: Nice answer, but aFter following the steps, I don't see how the value of the series if equal to the supremum of the series over a finite set.

Comment: I was just spelling out the definition of $\sup$. If you can prove the claims then you will have proved your problem.

Comment: So the definition of convergence of infinite series just says the partial sums converge to a number, say s. Then I have that $\sum_{n\in F}a_n > s-\epsilon$ Am I closer to finding F? So choose F such that $\sum_{n\in F}a_n > s-\epsilon$

Comment: Hopefully, if you choose $F$ correctly.

Comment: So choose F such that $\sum_{n\in F}a_n > s- \epsilon$?

Comment: Try to work out the complete proof and see if everything works out.

Comment: So all I know now is that $sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is an upper bound for F. Now don't just need to show it is also the least upper bound? How does showing there exists an F help? sorry I got lost

Comment: As I said, try to work out the complete proof. We can't help you at every single step.