# What are the elements of the set of finite partial sums of a set?

Tags: real-analysis

I was checking a proof in another question: [Show that the sum of a non-negative series is the supremum of its finite partial sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196372/show-that-the-sum-of-a-non-negative-series-is-the-supremum-of-its-finite-partial)

And just at the question statement:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}x_{n}= sup\left \{\sum _{n\in F}x_{n}:F\subset \mathbb{N} \hspace{0.1cm} is finite  \right \}$$

I don´t get what the elements of the set on the right side are. I know F is an index set, and i also know that the elements to be summed are non negative real numbers. What confused me is whether the numbers of elements being summed changes or is the length of the index set F what changes?

So, can someone help me understand what the elements of the set from where the supremum is going to be gotten are?

Comment: The sum is the sum over all finite subsets.  When the cardinality of the index set changes, the number of elements being summed changes.  After all, the two are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @saulspatz. Just to check, is the first element of the set on the right the sum of just one element and the last one the sum of infinite elements (which is the supremum)?

Comment: There isn't any order given for the set on the right, so you can't really talk about a "first" element, and certainly not about a last element.  There a no infinite sums on the right.  Let me try to explain the assertion.  First consider the set S of all possible finite sums of elements of the series.  Then take the least upper bound of the set (which may be $+\infty.$)  This is the sum of the series.

Comment: For example, if $x_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$, then some possible elements of the set are $\frac{1}{1^2}$, $\frac{1}{3^2}$, $\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{5^2}$, $\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{10^2} + \frac{1}{42^2} + \frac{1}{2018^2}$.  (And also, presumably 0 is in the set as an empty sum with $F = \emptyset$.)